# exit(header('location: index.php')); - Does this raise issues?

Tags: php

I always use the header then exit method. Recently I tried exit(header('location: index.php')); and it seems to work. Has anyone experienced any issue with this method?

Comment: even if working i think i would prefer to call them as 2 separate functions. And the header URI should be full not relative

Comment: Why should the URI be absolute?

Comment: because the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) says so :-) "HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself: "

Comment: Wow. I never thought. I've been doing wrong since PHP version 1. I wonder why it makes a difference? I cant think of anytime I chased a bug to that issue.

Comment: Older or very basic HTTP clients may be confused by relative URLs. The new [HTTP/1.1bis specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22#page-66) however permits non-absolute references. Practically all browsers implement them, since forever. (Personal preference: only using absolute URLs though.)

Comment: i have yet to find a browser that cares, but i feel its worth doing 'right' just in case

Comment: I guess I'm just old now. BTW +1 on the tip to make an absolute URI.

Answer (score 2):

It's no different to:

```
header('location: index.php'); exit;
```

When using `exit(header('location: index.php'));` the `header` function performs the redirect and then doesn't return anything, and calling `exit` with no parameter just exits without a custom message.

Comment: Technically speaking, `header()` likely returns null, resulting into a call to `exit(null)`.  This could theoretically be a little different than calling exit with no params, but there's probably little practical difference.

Comment: Well, the documentation says `No value is returned`, and they usually specify if `NULL` is returned, so I'm unsure if it's the same as `exit(NULL)`.

Comment: If you attempt to extract a return value from a function which does not return, you get `null` back.  Here's an example demonstrating as much: http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/wpg-8h3

Answer (score 1):

Exit takes an optional exit code so there is no reason why it shouldn't work. However, I would still break both lines for clarity and just in case a future version of php introduces unwanted behavior

Comment: Some of the best code I ever wrote was the code I removed from a project. The relocation header does not amount to much in most of my MVC projects. However, using the one-liner can reduce procedural code quite a bit (in the logic code). Maybe you're right. The former does read better.

Comment: If you want one line then why not `header('location: index.php'); exit;`?

Comment: Ok. You got me there. Technically speaking. LOL [Edit] Wait! my editor  breaks the lines on formatting. So technically...

Comment: Your point on future versions of PHP is probably more relevant than one might think. I can see where the header event could really be a candidate for change. Very good thought.

Comment: if($valid){\r\nheader(...);\r\nexit;\r\n} becomes one line: $valid?:exit(header(...)); This can add up across an app and it's still easy to read.